# How can I transform XAML text info inside a XML to HTML using XSLT?

Tags: html, xaml, xslt

I have a XML file which contains an element that has XAML formatted text inside. I want to simply transform it to HTML text using a XSLT stylesheet. The text is embedded in Section/Paragraph/Run. Formatting info transformation would be nice but not a must.

here is the original XML (I have removed some of the many Typography.xxx section attributes)

```
<Page_Information xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <Item_Description>
&lt;Section xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xml:space="preserve" TextAlignment="Left" LineHeight="Auto" IsHyphenationEnabled="False" xml:lang="en-us" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" NumberSubstitution.CultureSource="User" NumberSubstitution.Substitution="AsCulture" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontStyle="Normal" FontWeight="Normal" FontStretch="Normal" FontSize="15" Foreground="#FFFFFFFF" Typography.StandardLigatures="True" Typography.ContextualLigatures="True"  Typography.Fraction="Normal" Typography.StylisticAlternates="0"&gt;
&lt;Paragraph FontFamily="Tahoma"&gt;
&lt;Run FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="22.5"&gt;I WANT TO DISPLAY THIS TEXT HERE&lt;/Run&gt;
&lt;/Paragraph&gt;
&lt;Paragraph&gt;&lt;Run FontWeight="Bold"&gt;HELLO WORLD&lt;/Run&gt;
&lt;/Paragraph&gt;
&lt;/Section&gt;
</Item_Description>
</Page_Information>
```

the wanted output is:

```
<p><b>I WANT TO DISPLAY THIS TEXT HERE</b></p>
<p><b>HELLO WORLD</b></p>
```

any help is very much appreciated!
I tried `<xsl:value-of select="Item_Description" disable-output-escaping="yes"></xsl:value-of>` which works but removes all line breaks.

Comment: I would think that there are existing stylesheets that transform XAML to HTML, you would just need to extract the escaped XML in the `Item_Description` element and pass it to such a stylesheet, in XSLT 3 you could do that in one step using `parse-xml`, `xsl:import` or `transform` if needed. In earlier XSLT version you need various steps or the use of extension functions/objects to replace the use of `parse-xml` or `transform`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
<pre>
    <xsl:value-of select='Item_Description' disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</pre>
```

Comment: This removes all line breaks and displays
I WANT TO DISPLAY THIS TEXT HEREHELLO WORLD

I would need to reference each RUN elements. However, this does not seem to work (probably because of &gt; )

Comment: Are you sure? Try [this fiddle](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94AcskV)

Comment: Oh yes you are absolutely right!! It works when used inside the <pre> element!
Furthermore, I discovered why pre works, and found that I can also use it with CSS instead (defining styles in the HEAD section of the XSLT-HTML). So now I use:
  Paragraph {
                display: block;
                white-space: pre;
                margin: 1em 0;
                }
 [FontWeight="Bold"] {font-weight: bold;} 
 [TextAlignment="Center"] {text-align: center; } 

everything works like a charm!! Thanks for help!